# Primefaces SelectOneRadio with an noSelectionOption selected

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, selectoneradio

How can I have a selectOneRadio with an noSelectionOption which is selected by default?

I have the following:

```html
<p:selectOneRadio>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="none" noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.anything}"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

I want to have the "none" selected by default? How do I do that? As there is no "selected" Attribute for

Answer (score 2):

Use a managed bean field bound to your view with `null` value, also have your unselected option with `null` value.

JSF part:

```html
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.foo}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="none" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.anything}"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Managed bean code:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {
    //its value by default will be null
    private String foo;
    //getters and setters...
}
```

Comment: the value "null" is set in my backing bean, but if it return "null" the selectItem is not selected. Why?

Comment: me too, same problem